# Any type of system would be beneficial not to have a virtual memory

Tags: operating-system, ram, virtual-memory

I have a question about virtual memory.. Is there any type of system for which would be beneficial not to have a virtual memory? I would say that probably yes as long as we have enough of RAM, which is faster that Virtual memory in case we need to access something from the disk (which is extremely slow...) But also I know that some applications just require having paging.. Though I still think that some kind of system that maybe just always have the same amount of memory needed, maybe takes care of low level repetitive processes... Any thought of what kind of system it could be?

Comment: Do you have a toaster with a controller chip?

Comment: Yes, I do. Would that fall for that?

Comment: Well, it certainly would not be beneficial for your toaster to have a virtual memory subsystem.  It's expensive, unnecessary and, if it's like my toaster, would undercook or burn the toast anyway:)

Comment: Haha, that's funny. Thanks.

Comment: Washing machine would be another example, right?

Comment: @AnastasiaNetz - Most of the small-scale(miniscule) computing systems would not prefer to have the virtual-memory implementation. They would straight forward work on main-memory.

Comment: Like embedded systems that require just one straightforward process